# How to write a htaccess rule which adds a trailing forward slash to a url?

Tags: .htaccess

For example, for `www.example.com/foo/dosomething/`, I have such a htaccess document:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dosomething/$ myfile.php [L]
```

This htaccess file is inside my foo directory, which actually exists. But then I realised that, users who type the url in might forget the trailing forward slash, so they might type in this: `www.example.com/foo/dosomething`, and then he/she will get a 404. I don't want that, so I wrote this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^dosomething/$ myfile.php [L]
```

But then I remembered that this isn't SEO friendly, as two 'web pages' have the exact same content. So what I want now, is if the url doesn't have a trailing forward slash at the end, for the htaccess to redirect from, for example: `www.example.com/foo/dosomething` to `www.example.com/foo/dosomething/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /foo/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Before your `myfile.php` rule. The 301 redirect will ensure that search engine indexing will equate the 2 URLs.

Comment: Why is it giving me `/foo/myfile.php/`?

Comment: @think123 is the rule *before* your `RewriteRule $dosomething/^ myfile.php [L]` rule?

Comment: yeah, it is. would you be kind enough to provide the whole thing? I might have got something wrong there.

Comment: @think123 Oh, your rule has the `^` and `$` flipped. It should be `RewriteRule ^dosomething/$ myfile.php [L]`

Comment: oh that was an unintentional error, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @think123 edited answer, needed something to keep from looping